# MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

We have a Java Spring application that we are trying to deserialize the JSON string. We are encounter some issues when we attempt this. I have the following Java class:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Builder @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class BenefitRequest {
    RequestHeader           requestHeader;
    Provider                provider;
    Member                  member;
}
```

Here are the underlying objects that we are using for this application.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Builder @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class RequestHeader {
       String appointmentDt;
       String authReferralObtained;
       String indicator;
       String requestorFirstName;
       String requestorLastName;
       String requestorMidInitial;
       String requestDTM;
       String requestType;
       String packageId;
       String sequenceId;
       String userId;
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Builder @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Provider {
       String   providerId;
       String   providerTaxId;
       String   providerTaxonomy;
       String   providerName;
       String   providerFirstName;
       String   providerLastName;
       Address  providerAddress; 
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Builder @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Address {
     String address1;
     String address2;
     String city;
     String state;
     String zip; 
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Builder @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Member {
       String  memberId;
       String       firstName;
       String       lastName;
       String       middleName;
       String       dateOfBirth;
       String       gender;
       String       groupNumber; 
       Address      address;
}
```

Here is the code that we use to deserialize the JSON object that we pull from our database.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    BenefitRequest beneRequest = objectMapper.readValue(item.getRequestString(), BenefitRequest.class);
```

When we run this code we see the following error in our log files:

```
 [err] com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.xxx.model.BenefitRequest` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"requestHeader":{"appointmentDt":"2022-08-23","authReferralObtained":"Y","indicator":"L","requestorFirstName":"Darth","requestorLastName":"Vadar","requestorMidInitial":"","requestDTM":"2022-07-05","requestType":"CP","packageId":"abc124","sequenceId":"2","userId":"12333"},"provider":{"providerid":"000",
[err]   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
[err]   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1728)
[err]   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1353)
[err]   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._deserializeFromString(StdDeserializer.java:311)
[err]   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1495)
```

This is the complete JSON request that we are attempting to deserialize. It has some nested objects in it.

```
{
    "requestHeader": {
        "appointmentDt": "2022-08-23",
        "authReferralObtained": "Y",
        "indicator": "L",
        "requestorFirstName": "Darth",
        "requestorLastName": "Vadar",
        "requestorMidInitial": "",
        "requestDTM": "2022-07-05",
        "requestType": "CP",
        "packageId": "abc123",
        "sequenceId": "2",
        "userId": "12333"
    },
    "provider": {
        "providerId": "000",
        "providerTaxId": "1111111",
        "providerTaxonomy": "",
        "providerName": "Fam Dollar",
        "providerFirstName": "",
        "providerLastName": "",
        "providerAddress": {
            "address1": "123 Any Street",
            "address2": "",
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "zip": "11111"
        }
    },
    "member": {
        "memberId": "111",
        "firstName": "Luke",
        "lastName": "Skywalker",
        "middleName": "",
        "dateOfBirth": "",
        "gender": "",
        "groupNumber": "",
        "address": {
            "address1": "11 Blah Road",
            "address2": "",
            "city": "Town",
            "state": "",
            "zip": "22222"
        }
    }
}
```

I see others having similar problems. I did add the @AllArgsConstructor and tried adding the@Jacksonized too with no difference.

Comment: Could you please provide full objects structure and full JSON which you need to deserialize?

Comment: @Eugene does the data and objects added help clarify?

Comment: I have just tried to deserialize your example, it is working for me. Jackson version: 2.13.3 Lombok: 1.18.24